# Updating a Database With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to update my database records with the following code but am having no luck what so ever. Anybody care to help? Thanks

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Project Sproom</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
{

$newusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$newemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE users (Username, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$newusername."', '".$newemail."') WHERE UserID=".$_SESSION['UserID']."");
// }
?>
<div id="container">
<div id="homemenu">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="index.php" id="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="profile.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="homemain">
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
<p>This will be the edit profile when i have figured out how to do it...</p>
<br />
<form method="post" action="profile.php" name="editprofile" id="editprofile">
<label for="username">Username: </label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?=$_SESSION['Username']?>"/><br />
<label for="email">E-Mail: </label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['EmailAddress']?>"/> <br />
<input type="submit" name="editprofile" id="editprofile" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
} 
else
{
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;index.php">
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You're also missing a closing bracket somewhere. Maybe the one you've commented out just below the query? Or maybe you already found it, since your comment is gone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using INSERT syntax for an UPDATE query. The syntax should be like this:

```
UPDATE users SET Username = 'username', EmailAddress = 'email' WHERE UserID = 1;
```

[Docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't connected to the MySQL database, have you?

I didn't see that in this code...

Or is that part of the included "base.php" on top of this script?

I am afraid you need fist establish a connection to a certain MySQL database before trying to update a row in a table.

Edit:

Okay, well then. Try issue the following line of code after the update:

```
echo "edit was " .$edit;
```

This is to check whether the update query was executed successfully (in which case it should echoes true) or failed (in which case it echoes false).

So at least you can tell the result of such a mysql_query.

Comment: Yes, I have connected to the database in the base.php file. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Username='".$newusername."', EmailAddress='".$newemail."' WHERE  UserID=".$_SESSION['UserID']."");
```

Try this